# GridView: OnRowDatabound HeaderText Equals to ColumnText with AutoGenerateColumn True c# Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview with first columns is same as headers i.e. same value with autogeneratecolumns as true, what i need to do in RowDatabound if HeaderText Equals to Intersect of the first Column text, Change the color to Yellow. Please see the attached image of the Desireed Gridview Output.

[GridViewDesiredOutput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pTW9u.png)

HTML

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GvSamples" OnRowDataBound="GvSamples_RowDataBound" runat="server"  AutoGenerateColumns="True">
```

C#

```
 public void BindSamplesGrid()
    {
        DataTable _dt = new DataTable();
        _dt = BL.GetSample(_conn);
        GvSamples.DataSource = _dt;
        GvSamples.DataBind();
    }


protected void GvSamples_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < e.Row.Cells.Count; i++)
            {
                if (e.Row.Cells[i].Text == e.Row.Cells[i].Text)
                e.Row.Cells[i].Text = e.Row.Cells[i].Text.Replace("_", " ");
            }
        }
    }
```

I am using asp.net C# Gridview.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of issues with your code. First of all you can only access the header row in `DataControlRowType.Header`, so coloring the cells as desired must be done in `DataControlRowType.DataRow`.

Next you are evaluating exactly the same value, so it will always be true: `e.Row.Cells[i].Text == e.Row.Cells[i].Text`, although this does not seem to do much except replace a `_`, which has nothing to do with getting the cell color to be yellow.

The below snippet does what you need. It gets the current row number and colors the correct cell yellow.

```
protected void GvSamples_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    //check if the row is a datarow
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        //get the current row number
        int rowIndex = e.Row.RowIndex;

        //check if the rownumber does not exceed the column count
        if (rowIndex < e.Row.Cells.Count - 1)
        {
            //make the cell yellow
            e.Row.Cells[rowIndex + 1].BackColor = Color.Yellow;
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you VD, But the requirement is 1st column rows and header should be same. Please see the attached image. Thanks again

Comment: I just implemented and it works Please ignore my last comment, Thank you so much VD!